# Clojure core.cache :threshold gets doubled

Tags: caching, clojure

What am I missing here? I'm setting the `:threshold` to 2 but it's seems to use 4 instead.

version `[org.clojure/core.cache "0.6.2"]`

```
user=> (require '[clojure.core.cache :as cache])
nil

user=> (def foo (cache/fifo-cache-factory {} :threshold 2))
#'user/foo
```

using `cache/miss` [doc](http://clojure.github.com/core.cache/#clojure.core.cache/miss)

```
user=> (-> foo (cache/miss :1 1) (cache/miss :2 2) (cache/miss :3 3) (cache/miss :4 4))
{:4 4, :3 3, :2 2, :1 1}

user=> (-> foo (cache/miss :1 1) (cache/miss :2 2) (cache/miss :3 3) (cache/miss :4 4) (cache/miss :5 5))
{:5 5, :4 4, :3 3, :2 2}
```

using `assoc`

```
user=> (-> foo (assoc :1 1) (assoc :2 2) (assoc :3 3) (assoc :4 4))
{:4 4, :3 3, :2 2, :1 1}

user=> (-> foo (assoc :1 1) (assoc :2 2) (assoc :3 3) (assoc :4 4) (assoc :5 5))
{:5 5, :4 4, :3 3, :2 2}
```

If I set `:threshold 5` it allows 10 items. etc...
[This](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki/FIFO) is what I'm going off of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug in core.cache that was fixed in this commit:

https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/commit/b705f56b3e8e6d1bab97e1411e264fed48bc3694

I got the same behavior as you using 0.6.2, and got the correct results when I switched to 0.6.3-SNAPSHOT (available from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/).

Comment: That's what I suspected, but the github repo doesn't have issues enabled so I didn't know where to look. Thanks!